# perl code to find and substitute a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

```
output        [15:0] pin;                
output         [1:0] en;                
input          [6:0] dddr;            
input          [6:0] dbg;
```

replace this with

```
16 : pin : output;                         
2 : en : output;                
7 : dddr : input;            
7 : dbg :input;
```

I tried this code after opening the file and stored it in var. but i am not able to filter it like above

```
if ($var =~ /(\w+)\[(\d+)\:/) {  
    print "word=$1 number=$2\n";
}
```

//i am trying to add : in middle of the columns also

Comment: You are missing the whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the whitespace after the word characters in your pattern.

```perl
(\w+ )       \[(\d+):
      VVVVVVVV
output        [15:0] pin;
```

This is easily fixed. Add it into the pattern in between, like so:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /(\w+)\s+\[(\d+)\:/) {
        say "word=$1 number=$2";
    }
}

__DATA__
output        [15:0] pin;
output         [1:0] en;
input          [6:0] dddr;
input          [6:0] dbg;
```

This produces:

```
word=output number=15
word=output number=1
word=input number=6
word=input number=6
```

To get to your desired output, you'll have to refine the pattern and probably do some incrementing too.

Answer (score 5):

You are not taking account of the whitespace between `(\w+)` and the `(\d+)` parts of your regex.

```
while (<DATA>)
{
    if ( /(\w+)\s+\[(\d+)\:/) {  
        print "word=$1 number=$2\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
output        [15:0] pin;                
output         [1:0] en;                
input          [6:0] dddr;            
input          [6:0] dbg;
```

That outputs this

```
word=output number=15
word=output number=1
word=input number=6
word=input number=6
```

To get to your close to your final requirement, the regex can be expanded to match the other parts you need, as follows

```
while (<DATA>)
{
    if ( /(\w+)\s+\[(\d+)\:\d+\]\s+(.*);/) {  
        print "$2 : $3 : $1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
output        [15:0] pin;                
output         [1:0] en;                
input          [6:0] dddr;            
input          [6:0] dbg;
```

which outputs this

```
15 : pin : output
1 : en : output
6 : dddr : input
6 : dbg : input
```

Not sure how you calculate the value for the first column. It appears to be the number field + 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

One way to parse the shown data

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {             
    if ( /(\S+) \s+ \[ ([0-9]+):[0-9]+ \] \s+ (\S+) \s*;/x ) {
        say $2+1, ' : ', $3, ' : ', $1, ';';  
    }
}
```

Some comments follow.

In most regex patterns a lot depends on details of the input data format, and on how much flexibility there is in what data to expect and allow.

- That `\S+` matches a string of non-whitespace characters; that assumes that there is a single word in the beginning, that may contain any non-space characters. If there may be multiple words then use `.+?` instead, which matches all up to the first instance of the following pattern (here `;`, so better yet, can use `[^;]+`)
- I use the rather permissive `\S` as nothing is told about data. But if only "*word character*"s (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) are expected and allowed — and you want/need to enforce that — then use the far more restrictive `\w+`
- No spaces are allowed inside `[]`, only numbers with a `:` between them.  If it is OK for data to possibly have spaces then use `\[\s*` and `\s*\]`
- In the end, again one word is matched with `\S+`, with any non-space characters in it.  If more than one word can be expected then again use `.+?`.  If that part may contain semi-colons then you'd need `.+` which takes *everything* up to the very last `;`
- In all of this the `+` quantifier requires that there be at least one occurrence of the previous pattern. If it is acceptable that there is nothing in that place in data (that last word just missing for example) then use the `*` quantifier instead, like `.*`

So it is important to understand what the data is like *exactly*, as much as possible, and to thoughtfully articulate the requirements, in what precisely to restrict/allow.

---

A question came up of "*How to count the number of instances of patterns i.e `$1` `$2` `$3`*"

Add a hash as a frequency counter for particular values that get captured

```
my %val_freq;

while (<>) {             
    if ( /(\S+) \s+ \[ ([0-9]+):[0-9]+ \] \s+ (\S+) \s*;/x ) 
    {
        say $2+1, ' : ', $3, ' : ', $1, ';';  

        ++$val_freq{$_} for $1, $2, $3;
    }
}

say "$_ => $val_freq{$_}" for keys %val_freq;
```

Comment: How to count the number of instances of patterns i.e $1 $2 $3

Comment: @flash "_number of instances of patterns i.e $1 $2 $3_" -- not sure whether I understand: do you mean to count how many times each specific change happened?  -- For example: if 30 lines started with `output` then there are 30 `output` changes (`$1` being `output`), if `pin` came up 7 times then `$3` should've been `pin` 7 times ...?  If that's what you mean, then one can add a frequency counter (hash) --  inside that `if` add `++$freq{$1}` and this will count how many times each value captured by `$1` came up (same for `$2` and `$3`). Declare `%freq` before `while`. I can add that...?

Comment: @flash I just realized that I goofed it up by leaving out the `;` in the pattern (so it would get absorbed by `\S+` and `$3` would have it!).  This is because originally I had `\w+` there.  Fixed

Comment: @flash Added the frequency counter, at the end

Comment: @flash I had a typo in the code for the frequency counter that I added in the end (it said `use %val_freq`, duh).  Fixed